# Should I put 「名・姓」 on a business card to avoid confusion?

Tags: names

I'm getting some business cards made up and will have my Western name in both Latin and Katakana. I've noticed that sometimes there is a bit of confusion when I verbally tell people my name, with them sometimes opting to use my first name when they probably intended to use my family name.

To avoid this confusion I was thinking of adding 「名・姓」 to my business card right under the Katakana for my name. Is that the correct way to phrase the hint, and is it a good idea to include it? If not, what would you recommend to avoid this confusion?

For reference the card will look like this (example name):

#### John Smith

###### ジョン・スミス

「名・姓」

Answer (score 7):

People sometimes capitalize surnames to clarify although I'm not sure a lot of people do this for business cards.

That is, in case of John Smith, it is written

> John　　SMITH
> ジョン　スミス

---

At least if your name is uncommon enough (to the extent that most Japanese won't tell which is surname), I think it is reasonable to add 名・姓, but probably something like "ジョン(名)　スミス(姓)" with smaller fonts for 名・姓 looks better. (This is just an opinion.)

Comment: Thanks. Do you think many Japanese people would understand the significance of one name being in all caps though?

Comment: @user2141 From what I've seen, it is kind of common in academia, so I guess people with some research experience (i.e., those who have at least read some paper in college) can guess as such.